# APNS-PHP Push Notification Custom Properties

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The apns-push notification is working fine for me, but now I want to send some custom properties the app.

This is how I'm sending properties:

```
$message->setCustomProperty('Activities', $activities);
$message->setCustomProperty('Tasks', $tasks);
```

Both variables $activities and $tasks contains integer values, but the values are not being received on the app.

Any idea ?

Thanks...

Arfeen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't any problem in sending the custom properties, the problem was at the app end so this worked like charm.